# How to use a prepared statement correctly with Spring JDBCTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have to do a select query on a database which I will execute often. It works completely fine with a normal statement:

```
 List<Invoice> l = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
                     "SELECT id, name, stuff FROM example WHERE amount > ?",
                     new Object[] { "100" }, new RowMapper<Invoice>() {...} );
```

I execute the above statement very frequently, so for performance reason I want to use a prepared statement. However I'm now unsure how I correctly would use the spring API to achieve this.

I'm confused why spring would like me to give an instance of a `PreparedStatementCreator` as an argument for query? I thought that it's exactly the point that I do **not** create a new prepared statement every time I use the query method. So I think something along the line of the following snippet would be absolutely pointless as the prepared statement is created newly every time I call the `query`-method:

```
 List<Invoice> l = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
                     new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                         String query = "SELECT id, name, stuff FROM example WHERE amount > ?";
                         public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                              return connection.prepareStatement(query);
                         }
                     },
                     new PreparedStatementSetter() {...}, 
                     new RowMapper<Invoice>() {...} );
```

Do I have to create my own `ReusablePreparedStatementCreator`? Which would only create a new method on the first call of `createPreparedStatement`.

Could the `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory` help me?

So to rephrase, how would I correctly create a select query that uses a prepared statement with Spring JDBCTemplate to really gain a performance advantage without losing the advantage of the RowMapper?

Comment: Spring already uses a `PreparedStatement`, so no need to make it more complex.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have a official reference to this statment? I looked shortly into the code of JdbcTemplate::query(final String sql, final ResultSetExtractor<T> rse) and could not find any indication that this is true.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L1557 that is the inner class used when using one of the `query` methods. If you get a new statement or not also depends on  your jdbc driver and if it caches statements.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you! but in this case a new PreparedStatement object is created for each call to the query method. I might be wrong, but I think that does not gives me the improvement I try to achieve.

Comment: It depends on your JDBC provider if it is cached (and thus reused) or if a new one is created. Also I doubt that you want to cache the `PreparedStatement` because how are you going to execute it for the next connection? (Basically each transaction runs on its own connection).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure you would get a significant performance increase by not recreating the prepared statement every time, because the JDBC driver/database often caches prepared statements.

But if you want to execute multiple queries with a single prepared statement, simply use one of the [`execute()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCallback-) methods of JdbcTemplate, which creates a prepared statement from a SQL query (or lets you create it), and then executes a callback taking the prepared statement as argument. You can loop inside this callback, and execute the statement as many times you want.